# NEAR protocol ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm getting `ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined` when trying to use near-api-js.

The relevant lines of code are:

```
export const near = new Near({
  networkId,
  keyStore: new keyStores.BrowserLocalStorageKeyStore(),
  nodeUrl,
  walletUrl,
  headers: null,
});

export const walletConnection = new WalletConnection(near, appKeyPrefix);

walletConnection.requestSignIn({ // This line causes the problem
    contractId,
    methodNames: [],
});
```

My project is a fresh installation of Gatsby.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

I ran `yarn add buffer`.

Then I prepended my file with these lines:

```
import * as buffer from 'buffer';
(window as any).Buffer = buffer.Buffer; // https://github.com/isaacs/core-util-is/issues/27#issuecomment-878969583
```

See https://github.com/isaacs/core-util-is/issues/27#issuecomment-878969583

Then it seemed to work.

But this feels like a weird hack, and I didn't expect to need to do something like this. But I couldn't find any better way in any NEAR docs. I'm curious what other people will suggest here.

Answer (score 0):

This is pending issue in near-api-js, check here for more details, https://github.com/near/near-api-js/issues/757.

Might be resolve soon.